# How to redirect User after registration in opencart 2.0.3.1?

Tags: opencart2.x

My registration page URL like: `www.exmpl.com/index.php?route=account/register` when I submit after filled all fields then it redirect me to login page but I want to redirect it to thank you page.How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function (in /catalog/controller/account/register.php) is responsible for redirection (`$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/success'));`, to be more precise). Just need to check which page is "thank you" page (I'm not sure right now).

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            $customer_id = $this->model_account_customer->addCustomer($this->request->post);

            // Clear any previous login attempts for unregistered accounts.
            $this->model_account_customer->deleteLoginAttempts($this->request->post['email']);

            $this->customer->login($this->request->post['email'], $this->request->post['password']);

            unset($this->session->data['guest']);

            // Add to activity log
            $this->load->model('account/activity');

            $activity_data = array(
                'customer_id' => $customer_id,
                'name'        => $this->request->post['firstname'] . ' ' . $this->request->post['lastname']
            );

            $this->model_account_activity->addActivity('register', $activity_data);

            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/success'));
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But how can I redirect it my thank you page suppose my thank you page url link: www.exmpl.com/thank-you-page

Comment: Have you tried to write this?: `thank-you-page` instead of `account/success`? Is it working? If no, you may try (probably not that good option) replace entire line with this: `header('location: www.exmpl.com/thank-you-pag');`. It might work, but I'm not sure since I can't test it right now.

Comment: May you please guide me how to create a custom page in opencart v2.0. I am trying to create with the help of this link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-page-in-opencart--cms-22054 is it right?

Comment: This tutorial is showing different structure from opencart V 2.0.

Comment: I can: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=136937 If I helped a lot, please give an upvote/solved as it would really help me. Thanks! Good luck!